# Strange behavior for PESSIMISTIC_WRITE?

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, jpa-2.0

I am new to JPA 2.0 locking, so it might be I am missing something.

Using NetBeans, I tried to debug a Stateless Session Bean. I tried to switch between two threads to examine the concept:

```
   em.lock(entity, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
    em.persist(entity);
    try {
        em.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Already Locked!");
    }
```

I let the first process to finish

> em.flush();

(no exceptions). Then, I switched to the second process. Surprisingly - it **paused after the first line**, and **continued** only after the first process exited the function.

Note: It was all working as expected with LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC.

Is it a normal behavior? am I missing something? [here](http://sd-10807.dedibox.fr/show_items-feed=204d8d22d62a0c2ed8564a72b900958d) it seems to behave in a different way.

Thanks,

Danny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly normal behavior. Lock is released in transaction commit/rollback and that is not happening as a consequence of calling em.flush().

Comment: So the commit/rollback happens in this case only after function's termination?

Comment: If that is where border of your transaction is.